# Office365 Azure Active Directory Graph Client access with Small Business subscription

Tags: azure, office365, azure-active-directory

I have a new Office 365 Small Business subscription and am wondering how best to synchronize contacts with a custom in-house database application.

I have found material explaining how to access the underlying technology, Azure Active Directory with the a library called the Azure Active Directory Graph Client Library.

However, to my knowledge I don't have an Azure Management Portal for the Azure technologies underlying Office 365, and that's where I would normally register my application for API access according to those tutorials.

So, if I want to access the Azure Active Directory in my Office365 account with the Azure Active Directory Graph Client Library, where do I register the application, get my key - and to which host do I connect to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Office 365 uses Azure Active Directory as identity management, so it is already there. To access Windows Azure portal for your existing Office 365 subscriptions all you need is to activate a free Windows Azure subscription on your existing account .

This blog [Using your Office 365 Azure AD tenant with application access enhancements for Windows Azure AD](http://blogs.technet.com/b/ad/archive/2013/09/10/empower-your-office-365-subscription-identity-management-with-application-access-enhancements-for-windows-azure-ad.aspx) gives a very detailed steps on how to do it.

Comment: Awesome, that was the missing piece. Thanks!